# Grafana won't connect to InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, grafana

The database, username, and password combination definitely work. The following configuration for grafana doesn't tho.

```
datasources: {
  influxdb: {
    type: 'influxdb',
    url: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:8086/db/dbname",
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    default: true
  },
},
```

I've tried removing the `default` parameter, changing `influxdb` to `influx`, and append `/series` to the url, all to no avail. Has anyone gotten this to work?

- InfluxDB v0.7.3 (git: 216a3eb)
- Grafana 1.6.0 (2014-06-16)

Comment: That is strange, the default property is required on at least one datasource (I it will be optional after v1.6.1). To understand what could be causing issues it would help greatly with chrome developer tools output for the failing influxdb request, like what request is failing, what parameters/headers was sent, and what the response is.

Comment: Can you update this question with what the problem was? So just not sits here with no accepted answer

Comment: @Torkel i hear you. Not on the project anymore but will try to find time this weekend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using this below configuration and it works. Try insert the grafana database into your db and add grafana db configuration.

> ...
>
> datasources: {
>
> ```
>     influxdb: {
>       type: 'influxdb',
>       url: "http://localhost:8086/db/test",
>       username: 'root',
>       password: 'XXXX'
>     },
>     grafana: {
>       type: 'influxdb',
>       url: "http://localhost:8086/db/grafana",
>       username: 'root',
>       password: 'XXXX',
>       grafanaDB: true
>     }
>   },
> ```
>
> ...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using the config shown by annelorayne above. It turned out that Grafana was not able to connect to localhost:8086, but it could connect to the actual IP address of the server (ie. 10.0.1.100:8086).

This was true even though 'telnet localhost 8086' worked.

I changed the Grafana config to this, and it worked:

```
  datasources: {
    influxdb: {
      type: 'influxdb',
      url: "http://10.0.1.100:8086/db/collectd",
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      grafanaDB: true
    },
    grafana: {
      type: 'influxdb',
      url: "http://10.0.1.100:8086/db/grafana",
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root'
    },
  },
```

I'm sorry I can't explain why this happens. Since telnet works, I have to assume it's a Grafana issue.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked multiple times on the mailing list. See these threads for more info [thread1](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/influxdb/1406146134.33273.YahooMailNeo%40web160201.mail.bf1.yahoo.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer), [thread2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/influxdb/grafana/influxdb/tx59JS7HvOY/oJ66FhQTkYwJ), [thread3](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/influxdb/7f975871-af22-4e74-8fe5-c78d8d87d90a%40googlegroups.com). There's also a blog post on how to get grafana and InfluxDB working together [here's a link](http://www.philipotoole.com/influxdb-and-grafana-howto)

Answer (score 0):

The browser sometimes caches the config.js and therefore looks at old configurations.
Please try clearing the cache or use incognito/private mode to load grafana dashboard.
I faced the same issue and using incognito worked for me.

Verify the config.js contents using grafana( host:port/config.js) .